# What is this python syntax? Repeatedly call a function with iterable and package return values as array

Tags: python, iterable

This line is found in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit):

```
 future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
```

It seems to repeatedly call a function (`submit`) using arguments  from a list (`URLS`)

What is the name for this syntax (idiom?).

Is `future_to_url` a list?

Comment: That's a dictionary comprehension

Comment: @Chris_Rands so the 'submit' functions are not actually called in this line?

Comment: You should follow the link and read about comprehensions. The answer to your question is yes, they are called. How about printing future_to_url at your interpreter?

Comment: Submit will be called for every element in URLS, the resulting value will the key in the dictionary